# why '__getattr__ ' is not printing characters in python

Tags: python

I've encountered this problem. I'm reading this 'learning python' book, looking into delegation. And I'm running under python 3.4.

```
class C():
    data='spam'
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        print ('getattr:'+name)
        return getattr(self.data,name)


X=C()
X.__getitem__(0)
```

When I run the following code, the console returned nothing but :

```
getattr:__getitem__
```

Why didn't it print out a character as the book says?

Comment: What exact book are you reading that suggests such a thing as this? Are you sure that, that's its example, and you've not altered something, or expecting something else etc...

Comment: It should not print a character but should return a character (`s`).

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure. I didn't alter a thing and the outcome should have a character printed other than the result I got. The book is 'learning python 5th edition', pg 990.

Comment: @A.E.Drew Oh I got it. The character 'printed' is actually a echo. I was using a IDE so I got nothing. Thank you.